# How can I create dynamic text views according to a selected integer from a spinner?

Tags: java, android, listview

> 03-05 11:31:07.042    1897-1897/com.example.project.a D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
>       --------- beginning of crash
>   03-05 11:31:07.050    1897-1897/com.example.project.a E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>
> EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.project.a, PID: 1897
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.project.a/com.example.project.a.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.removeAllViews()' on a null object reference
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)

---

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

```
        //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"The day qqq"+arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String control2=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();

       int  noOfBulb= (int) spinner1.getSelectedItem();
        final TextView tryText2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tryText2.setText("No"+noOfBulb);

        mdynamiclayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamiclayout);
        mdynamiclayout.removeAllViews();//need to remove the view before it create
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfBulb; i++) {//6 is your selected item from spinner it can be any nymber
            TextView t = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            t.setText("value" + i);
            //  t.setTextSize(20);
            //  t.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            mdynamiclayout.addView(t);
        }

    }

    public  void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){}

}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SelectBulbs();


    rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);

    tv1 = new TextView (MainActivity.this);


    tv1.setText("Dynamic TextView");


    tv1.setTextColor(Color.RED);


    tv1.setTextSize(20);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            ((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params1.leftMargin=115;
    params1.topMargin=120;



   rl.addView(tv1);
```

---

```
public class Unit {
    private  String  _bulbNo;

    public  Unit(String bulbNo) {

        _bulbNo = bulbNo;


    }
    public  String getBulbNo(){
        return  _bulbNo;
    }

}
// I created this class


 private  void addBulbsFans(String bulb)
    {
        Units.add(new Unit(bulb));
    }
```

//I add this method to MainActivity.java .After this i need to know how  to pass the spinner value from a buttonclick event.

Comment: check it out my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a dynamic textview in vertical order then create LinearLayout in xml and Orientation as Vertical as like below

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dynamiclayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/registerlayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/registerlayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

Then add below line of code in your activity

```
private LinearLayout mdynamiclayout;

mdynamiclayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamiclayout);

        mdynamiclayout.removeAllViews();//need to remove the view before it create
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {//6 is your selected item from spinner it can be any nymber
            TextView t = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            t.setText("value" + i);
            mdynamiclayout.addView(t);
        }
```

Passing one activity to another activity :

```
Intent intent_value = new Intent(Mainactivity.this,
                yoursecondactivity.class);
        intent_value.putExtra("key", value);
        intent_value.putExtra("key2", value2);
        startActivity(intent_value);
```

Retrieve value:

```
 Intent getValues = getIntent();
    String value1 = getValues.getStringExtra("key");
```

Let me know if you need any help

Comment: The program is crashing when i give as mdynamiclayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamiclayout);  I just did exacly as your code.

Comment: I cant figure out the issue with this single line can you post your full coding in question, so that it will make more sense, post logcat also

Comment: yah sure ! I'll add it

Comment: I'm sorry I just couldn't trouble you anymore. I tried it so many ways and i got the default value only . The exact value passed from there couldn't be reached                                   int value1 = getValues.getIntExtra("key2",1);

Comment: Because i needed an interger from that I put that getIntExtra. And i used a textView just to view it's return value and it printed as '1' the deault value i put

Comment: just use as like my code after get the value String value1 = getValues.getStringExtra("key"); , user parser to get integer value as like below Integer.ParseInt(value1)

Comment: OMG! It's working!!! I really don't know how should i thank you. I'm soo happy! Thanx a lot! I really mean it! You saved me!!!!

Comment: I'm really sorry I tried to vote up but it says i need to have at least 15 reputation but I  don't have cause I just joined this yesterday! I will do it for sure whenever I collected them! I marked it as the correct answer!Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert selected String to integer by following

```
 int value = Integer.valueOf(spiner.getselecteditem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `Integer.valueOf()`, in your case it would be like that:

```
String[] bulbs = {"0","1","2","3","4","5"};
Integer[] bulbsConvert = new Integer[6];
//Array to int
for(String item : bulbs){
   bulbsConvert.add(Integer.valueOf(item));
}
```